# Cast to a type by its OID?

Tags: python, postgresql, libpq

I would like to cast a value to a type using not the type name, but the OID of the type. Is this possible? So instead of:

```sql
SELECT '{{a}}'::char[]
```

do

```sql
SELECT '{{a}}'::1002
```

(although the above results in a syntax error)

Context: I'm writing a library in Python to query PostgreSQL, which includes conversions from PostgreSQL types to Python types, and I want to make sure I test all the types, and it seems easiest to go through all the OIDs listed at https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/include/catalog/pg_type.dat

Comment: I'd like to do something similar - did you ever get this to work, or have to refactor to a different approach?

Answer (score 2):

I dont know about the possibility to call by oid, but
why not just in your library in python use the table pg_type , if you have the postgresql database?
i guess you want to build the automatic test for you mappings between types of Postgresql and Python, so you before checks can query from that table relevant information about build-in types in Postgresql

```
select *  from pg_type
```

you can filter by typtype (base type or others) and by typcategory (numeric, arrays , etcs)

[The doc about pg_type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-type.html)

p.s. Hope this will help =)